# Usage of compound conditional statements within JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript

Can you use a compound conditional statement in a JavaScript for loop?

Here is an example,

```
//using a compound conditional statement
//within a for loop, JavaScript
for (var i=0; i < res.length && i < 5; i++) {};

//or
for (var i=0; i < res.length || i < 5; i++) {};
```

Comment: Is the fact that your second example might run infinitely an example of such a logic error or just serendipitous irony?

Comment: It's a logic statement like any other; any errors will be PEBKAC.

Comment: Serendipitous irony for sure! :)

Comment: @Niko—I think you mean "yes", the question has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it could lead to a logic error -- like any other code. Hopefully you test your code so you can find those errors and fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Brent - The two statements are not the same. You are trying to use [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). hence the second statement should read

```
for (var i=0; i >= res.length || i >= 5; i++) {};
```

It would be better to do this

```
var end = res.length < 5 ? res.length : 5;

for (var i=0; i < end; ++i) {}
```

This will reduce the overhead or doing the logic of working out when to terminate the loop.